# What is lim sup (x/n)?

Tags: limits

can you please tell me what 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in D} \frac{x}{n},$$
 with $D = (0, \infty)$ is? I'm pretty sure the supremum doesn't exist, but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $n$, we have $\sup_{x\in(0,D)}\frac xn = +\infty$, hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in(0,D)}\frac xn = +\infty$ (if one calls a supremum/limit with infinite value existent).

Comment: n the OP $D$ is a set. In your post $D$ is a number.